# Ubuntu 14.04 mouse pointing problem

Tags: 14.04, mouse, google-chrome

I have a problem with mouses on my two computers. I will try to describe that issue:
When I point some tab in Google Chrome and try to click, it clics a little below... I need to resize Google Chrome window and it works for a while.
Second issue is sometimes I can't click on folders on the left corner of desktop. The others folders are OK...
Any advices?
Regards

Comment: Is the mouse position only offset for Chrome or does it happen for other apps?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem https://askubuntu.com/q/471995/285006, to fix it, i did the steps described on this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219222

> CompizConfig option Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher > Show live previews of windows in the Switcher. When the option is checked the mouse mismatch doesn't occur

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However it was with Nautilus file managing system for me. But later other floating widgets also got affected.

Go to CompizConfig Settings manager and search for Ubuntu Unity Plugin.

Then Switcher > Show live previews of windows in the switcher.

Check this option.