# Google Chrome mouse accuracy bug - 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, mouse, google-chrome

I installed Google Chrome from the official repository http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

While using it I noticed a strange bug - when I focused on Desktop ( <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - <kbd>SUPER</kbd> - <kbd>D</kbd> ) and then gave back focus to the chrome window the mouse cursor would be around `5px` above where it appeared to be on screen and did not match where I was clicking. This affects links as well as chrome interface (menus etc).

[image - trying to click link on askubuntu.com](https://imageshack.us/i/pnZhft5Vj)

When I toggle Chrome window maximization state the mouse cursor works correctly. This issue does not occur on Linux Mint.

Is there a solution ?

```
GNU/Linux x86_64 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP
```

Comment: FWIW, it doesn't happen on my Google Chrome on the dev channel.

Comment: This is possibly related to http://askubuntu.com/questions/469341/ubuntu-14-04-mouse-pointing-problem. A related bug report is found at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1311323.

Comment: thank you edwinksl - the solution was to open CompizConfig and enable option Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher > Show live previews.

Comment: Sounds good. In that case, I will flag this question as a duplicate of the question that I linked.